# What is "epoch" in keras.models.Model.fit?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, batch-processing

What is "epoch" in `keras.models.Model.fit`? Is it one gradient update? If it is more than one gradient update, then what is defining an epoch?

Suppose I am feeding my own batches to `fit`. I would regard "epoch" as finishing to process entire training set (is this correct)? Then how to control keras for this way? Can I set `batch_size` equal to `x` and `y` size and `epochs` to 1?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here is how Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#what-does-sample-batch-epoch-mean) defines an epoch:

> **Epoch**: an arbitrary cutoff, generally defined as "one pass over the entire dataset", used to separate training into distinct phases, which is useful for logging and periodic evaluation.

So, in other words, a number of epochs means how many times you go through your training set.

The model is updated each time a batch is processed, which means that it can be updated multiple times during one epoch. If `batch_size` is set equal to the length of `x`, then the model will be updated once per epoch.